# Texas Instruments Compiler

Tags: compiler, development, ide, 8051, licensing

I am working with TI's CC2533 SoC Low Power RF

I bought a few chips and assembled a few PCBs.. Using TI's debugger I confirmed that I can send and receive packets using the basic RF using the RFStudio.

Something I have not realised is that TI does not have an IDE for this and uses IAR Workbench 8051 with a TI downloadable SimpliciTI Protocol stack that is supposed to plug into IAR.

The problem is that the software is only 30 day trial and costs nearly 2000 dollars.

Has any body here compiled any firmware using some opensource or free IDE for this series of SoC?

As I jumped off the Arduino band wagon straight onto this.. I assumed there would be an IDE available for general use.. especially because I bought the official dev kit.

Comment: A similar, but easier to work with device is the Wixel from Pololu, http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1336 They provide an Arduino-like environment for a similar chip (CC2510), still 2.4GHz, but not 802.15.4

Comment: I have seen that before. I made my PCB's for 5usd.. without any balun, using symetrical PCB antenna, no  led's, or regulators - just bare minimum that runs of 3.2volt battery. the 2533 has built in regulator (and charging) which is great.. The pin outs the are the same.. so i think their software will work.. but it might be limited.. thanks anyway.. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the Chipcon 8051 SoCs are supported by the open source SDCC compiler. But, all you get is a compiler, no examples or demos.

There's no available port of SimpliciTI for SDCC.

There is a port of Contiki, an open source operating system for wireless sensors.
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Getting_started_with_Contiki_and_CC2530

Comment: Great. Will take a look into that. That should work with 2533.. will investige Thanks

Comment: I tried it and don't really know how to use it. Got it running in the VM.. and then lost a bit :( I got IAR to work.. but yea..

Comment: Have you gotten any further with this?